# fluttersms recipients are not recognisable

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sms

I am trying to send sms to a fixed phone number but it doesn't work properly. When I run the code in a virtual device in android studio there isn't a problem but when people download the app in play store it shows the recipient in brackets[ ] and that makes the recipient not recognisable in some phones so the app doesn't send the sms.The app is for appointments to hair salons but I'm not using database. thanks.
(as you can see I tried .replace but that didn't work)

```
         List<String> p=[
              '12345678',
              '11223344',
            ];

            class HairsalonConfirm extends StatelessWidget {
                  String x, n, d, t, ty, no;

                  void _sendSMS(String message, List<String> recipents) async {
                    String _result =
                        await FlutterSms.sendS

        MS(message: message, recipients: recipents);
                _message = _result;
              }
              HairsalonConfirm(
                  {@required this.x, this.n, this.no, this.t, this.d, this.ty});
              @override
              Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                return Scaffold(
    ...// other code
                        const SizedBox(height: 40),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Container(
                              width: 280.0,
                              height: 50.0,
                              child: RaisedButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  _sendSMS(x, [p[8].replaceAll('[', '').replaceAll(']', '').trim()]);
                                  NameController.clear();
                                  timeCtl.clear();
                                  dateCtl.clear();
                                  TypeController.clear();
                                  NotesController.clear();
                                  Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                              MyHomePage()));
                                },
...//some code
```

Comment: Please, make it more specific in which widget you are facing some problems. It's hard to find out the problem by reading this large snippet.

Comment: I edited it and removed some of the extra code. The problem is that the recipient has to be List<String> and I want to only send it to one person so a say as you can see p[0]. but that it string so I found that it only recognises it if I write it like [p[0]] and tsowhen I send the sms sometimes the phone shows like [123456789] instead of 123456789 but other devices its okay.thanks in advance for the help

Comment: If you want send SMS to one person, then why are you taking parameters as a List<String> instead of just a single String?

Comment: I tried that but at the part where it says message: message, recipient: recipient it says that it must be a list and that's basically the problem because it want let me just use string

Comment: and yes I tried changing the part above that form List<String> recipient to String recipient but the same problem appears

Comment: Can you just print the parameter recipents in the method _sendSms by using print function of Dart and debug that by connecting to the devices you are facing the exact issue? I guess that ".replaceAll('[', '').replaceAll(']', '').trim()" is messing with your data.